# Get random link from page using Shell

Tags: shell, curl

I'm trying to write a very basic benchmarking script which will load random pages from a website, starting with the home page.

I will be using curl to grab the contents of the page, but then I want to load a random next page from that as well. Could someone give me a bit of Shell code that will get the URL from a random a href from a the output of the curl command?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with:

```
curl <url> 2> /dev/null | egrep "a href=" | sed 's/.*<a href="//' | \
cut -d '"' -f 1-1 | while read i; do echo "`expr $RANDOM % 1000`:$i"; done | \
sort -n | sed 's/[0-9]*://' | head -1
```

Replacing the  bit with the URL you are trying to get a link from.

EDIT:
It might be easier to make a script called getrandomurl.sh containing:

```
#!/bin/sh

curl $1 2> /dev/null | egrep "a href=" | sed 's/.*<a href="//' | \
cut -d '"' -f 1-1 | while read i; do echo "`expr $RANDOM % 1000`:$i"; done | \
sort -n | sed 's/[0-9]*://' | head -1
```

and run it like `./getrandomurl.sh http://stackoverflow.com` or something.

Comment: That's fantastic, thanks! Only trouble is it seems to load javascript sometimes as well. Is there a way to make it so it'll only load links to actual pages?

Comment: What do you mean by "load javascript"?

Comment: Try running it on http://www.google.co.uk/ for example. Sometimes the output will be JS code.

Comment: If the OP is willing to relax the requirements a little: `lynx -dump http://www.google.com |sed -e '0,/^References/{d;n};s/.* \(http\)/\1/'` can be used to get the list of hrefs on a page more safely (with a help of real HTML parser)

Comment: I'm afraid you would need an actual parser for that... otherwise it would just be too complicated (I don't think you actually can parse html with just regex)

Answer (score 1):

Using both lynx and bash arrays:

```
hrefs=($(lynx -dump http://www.google.com |
sed -e '0,/^References/{d;n};s/.* \(http\)/\1/'))
echo ${hrefs[$(( $RANDOM % ${#hrefs[@]} ))]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a `curl` solution, but I think more effective given the task.

I would suggest using the `perl` `WWW::Mechanize` module for this. For example to dump all links from a page use something like this:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;

$mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get("URL");
$mech->dump_links(undef, 'absolute' => 1);
```

Note `URL` should be replaced with the wanted page.

Then either continue within `perl`, the following follows a random link on the `URL` page:

```
$number_of_links = "" . @{$mech->links()};
$mech->follow_link( n => int(rand($number_of_links)) )
```

Or use the `dump_links` version above to get urls and process further within shell, e.g. to get random url (if the above script is called `get_urls.pl`):

```
./get_urls.pl | shuf | while read; do
  # Url is now in the $REPLY variable
  echo "$REPLY"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using pup

A flexible solution to getting all the links on a page is to use [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup) to specify [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors). For instance, I can grab all the links (`<a>` tags) from my blog using:

```
curl https://jlericson.com/ 2>/dev/null \
| pup 'a attr{href}'
```

The `attr{href}` at the end outputs only the `href` attribute. If you run that command, you'll notice several links aren't to posts on my site, but to my email address and Twitter account.

If I want to get just the blog post links, I can be a bit more choosy:

```
curl https://jlericson.com/ 2> /dev/null \
| pup 'a.post-link attr{href}'
```

That grabs only links with `class='post-link'`, which are the links to my posts.

Now we can select a random line of output:

```
curl https://jlericson.com/ 2> /dev/null \
| pup 'a.post-link attr{href}' \
| shuf | head -1
```

The `shuf` command mixes the lines like a deck of cards and `head -1` draws the top card off the deck. (Or the first line, if you prefer.)

My links are all relative, so I will want to append the domain using `sed`:

```
curl https://jlericson.com/ 2> /dev/null \
| pup 'a.post-link attr{href}' \
| sed -e 's|/|https://jlericson.com/|' \
| shuf | head -1
```

The `sed` command replaces the first `/` with the rest of the URL.

I might also want to include the text of the link. That gets a bit tricky because `pup` doesn't support two output functions. But it does support outputting to JSON, which can be read with `jq`:

```
curl https://jlericson.com/ 2> /dev/null \
| pup 'a.post-link json{}' \
| jq -r '.[] | [.text,.href] | @tsv' \
| sed -e 's|/|https://jlericson.com/|' \
| shuf | head -1
```

This is a tab-separated value output, which may or might not be what you want.